# Create new .xlsx file and write to it with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I couldn't find an existing thread fitting my problem and now I'm stuck and searching for help ;)

What I want to accomplish: Several .xlsx tables filled with content are in the same folder, I want to pick the same two cells' content out of every file and save it to a newly created .xslx file named "Summary.xlsx".

My makro reads out the cells' content properly and also saves the Summary.xlsx. However it looks like the file is corrupted because when I try to open it Excel would show me just a blank page (not even a sheet).

Watching the file using breakpoints, the headlines get written properly: However the table in Summary.xlsx starts to disappear right when I try to write the content of the other files in the do-while-loop.

Additional info: I start the makro from an extra makro-file in the same directory as the other files using the play button in the module.

Here's my code.

Warning: I'm new to VBA, obviously :)

```
Sub MergeMakro()

Dim directory As String, fileName As String, otherWorkbook As Workbook, sumFileName As String, sumFilePath As String, i As Integer

thisFileName = "MergeMakro.xlsm"
sumFileName = "Summary.xlsx"
sumFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sumFileName

' If sum file already exists, delete it
If Dir(sumFilePath) <> "" Then
Kill (sumFilePath)
End If

' create new sum file
Set sumWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=sumFilePath

Set sumSheet = sumWorkbook.ActiveSheet

' search in the file's directory
directory = "R:\ExcelStuff\Auswertungen\"

' headlines -> are written properly
sumSheet.Range("A1") = "Materialnummern"
sumSheet.Range("B1") = "Bezeichnung"
sumSheet.Range("C1") = "Gesamtkosten"

' start at line 2
i = 2

fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xls")

Do While fileName <> ""

    If fileName <> thisFileName And fileName <> sumFileName Then

        Set otherWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(directory & fileName)

        ' do not show windows
        If Not (ActiveWorkbook Is Nothing) Then
            ActiveWindow.Visible = False
        End If

        ' remove last 5 chars of string (.xlsx)
        fileName = Left(fileName, Len(fileName) - 5)

        ' do not try to open the makro-file itself
        Set otherSheet = otherWorkbook.Sheets(fileName)

        ' write data into file -> here the file starts to get corrupted
        sumSheet.Range("A" & i) = fileName
        sumSheet.Range("B" & i) = otherSheet.Range("C4")
        sumSheet.Range("C" & i) = otherSheet.Range("G4")

        i = i + 1

        otherWorkbook.Close

    End If

    ' get the next file
    fileName = Dir()

Loop

Workbooks(sumFileName).Save
Workbooks(sumFileName).Close

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried disabling `ActiveWindow.Visible = False`? That may cause that you don't see the content during debug. Also have a look on the output without closing it (disable `Workbooks(sumFileName).Close`)

Comment: @MátéJuhász Thank you very much!
Edit: Not disabling the visible property did the trick :)

Comment: You may also want to force coding of your file using fileformat:=51. Format 51 is for xlsx. Format 52 is for xlsm. Used like ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=sumFilePath, fileformat:=51 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx

Comment: @99moorem Appreciate your input, it works like a charm!